# how to do a gradient background that is not fixed and changes on scroll(css)

Tags: html, css

So I want to do a gradient background, that do change on scroll - I mean I want to make it look like this:

---

top of the page before scrolling:

[image: top of the page before scrolling]

bottom of the page after scrolling:

[image: bottom of the page after scrolling]

---

I use this code now:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(255, 255, 255), rgba(237, 255, 188, 0.5));
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

but it doesn't work - it stays fixed and no matter where on the page I am, background color stays the same.

Comment: simply removing `background-attachment: fixed;` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `background-attachment:fixed` to `background-attachment:scroll`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2187/

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer - hope it helps for the others too..

(so your suggestions(all of them) do not work! 
It breaks the background if i change this property, cos the page is long.
The only way i could make it work was with property height set on auto.

```
height:auto;
```

this fixed my problem.